# How to run a least squares fitting over implicit variables INSIDE a double integration?

Tags: data-visualization, least-squares, matlab, curve-fitting, numerical-integration

I am trying to create an algorithm to fit dI/dV data from a superconducting sample, and eventually a GUI.

There is a double integration involved over the product of two functions Fermi function and density of states), both of which contain the independent variables order parameter, temperature and broadening parameter.
To perform the double integration, I ran a loop over a sum function which contains the product of this superconducting DOS and Fermi function.

The DOS itself is a function of broadening function, order parameter (gap) and temperature, but the result of the integral is what needs to fit to the curve. This has the independent variables as implicit variables.

How, and at what point of the code,  do I introduce a least squares fit that will vary the broadening function and order parameter values to best fit the curve?

I am trying to write the code in matlab, if this helps.